# Splitting a dataframe based on the index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I would like to split the below DF_input based on the index. That's from the below DF, How to obtain:

```
       measurement      value
0              0        13
1              1         3
2              2         4
0              0         8
1              1        12
2              2        34 
3              5        54
```

DF_output1

```
       measurement      value
0              0        13
1              1         3
2              2         4
```

DF_output2

```
       measurement      value
0              0         8
1              1        12
2              2        34 
3              5        54
```

What I did is the following:`

```
            df_input.reset_index(inplace=True)         
            shifted = df_dataset['index'].shift()
            m = shifted.diff(-1).ne(0.000000)             
            a = m.cumsum()
            aa = df_dataset.groupby([df_dataset.uuid,a])                

            for k, gp in aa:
                print(gp)
```

What Am I doing wrong? Any help please would be very appreciated.
Best Regards, Carlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `groupby` to partition the index into separate dataframes of increasing subsequence:

```
for _, g in df.groupby((df.index.to_series().diff().fillna(1) < 0).cumsum()):
     print(g, '\n')

   measurement  value
0            0     13
1            1      3
2            2      4 

   measurement  value
0            0      8
1            1     12
2            2     34
3            5     54
```

This solution is a little more flexible because it does not define groups based on whether they begin with `0`, but rather finds increasing subsequences in the index.

Comment: @CarloAllocca Assumption from looking at your code is that you are trying to find each increasing subsequence. Is this assumption correct? If no, this answer is useless. If yes, the other answers will not help you.

Comment: OK. I see. You assumption is partially correct, in sense that in my case each subsequence starts always from 0. My solution posted above does exactly this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
a = df.index.to_series().eq(0).cumsum()
print (a)
0    1
1    1
2    1
0    2
1    2
2    2
3    2
dtype: int32
aa = df.groupby(a)

for k, gp in aa:
    print(gp)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby` on index like

```
In [4266]: for n, g in df.groupby((df.index == 0).cumsum()):
      ...:     print g
      ...:
   measurement  value
0            0     13
1            1      3
2            2      4
   measurement  value
0            0      8
1            1     12
2            2     34
3            5     54
```

Better to store it has dict.

```
In [4264]: {n: g for n, g in df.groupby((df.index == 0).cumsum())}
Out[4264]:
{1:    measurement  value
 0            0     13
 1            1      3
 2            2      4, 2:    measurement  value
 0            0      8
 1            1     12
 2            2     34
 3            5     54}
```

Timing on partition methods

```
In [4279]: df.shape
Out[4279]: (7000, 3)

In [4280]: %timeit (df.index == 0).cumsum()
1000 loops, best of 3: 118 µs per loop

In [4281]: %timeit df.index.to_series().eq(0).cumsum()
1000 loops, best of 3: 420 µs per loop

In [4282]: %timeit (df.index.to_series().diff().fillna(1) < 0).cumsum()
1000 loops, best of 3: 623 µs per loop

In [4284]: df.shape
Out[4284]: (70000, 4)

In [4285]: %timeit (df.index == 0).cumsum()
1000 loops, best of 3: 328 µs per loop

In [4286]: %timeit df.index.to_series().eq(0).cumsum()
1000 loops, best of 3: 805 µs per loop

In [4287]: %timeit (df.index.to_series().diff().fillna(1) < 0).cumsum()
100 loops, best of 3: 1.42 ms per loop
```

Comment: Many Thanks Zero. I understand to groupby on  the index, but it is not clear why I should store it has dic?

Comment: My solution does not do the same thing your does, so comparing mine to you's guys is unfair :p

Comment: Uhm, OP asked for an output, all methods try to get there, hence the FYI benchmark, if addons in your method aren't needed for someone, they could pick which one to use. Benchmarks at-least help someone to look at their use-case and pick what's needed, doesn't mean this solution fits for all scenarios. My 2c!

Answer (score 1):

This is my answer:

```
        df_input.reset_index(inplace=True)         
        shifted = df_dataset['index'].shift()
        m = shifted.diff(-1).gt(0.000000)             
        a = m.cumsum()
        aa = df_dataset.groupby([df_dataset.uuid,a])                

        for k, gp in aa:
            print(gp)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution ...(really hard think out side box )

```
df=df.reset_index()
ll=df.loc[df.measurement==0,].index.values.tolist()

for i in range(len(ll)) :
    if i<len(ll)-1:
        print(df.loc[ll[i]:(ll[i+1]-1)])
    else :
        print(df.loc[ll[i]:])


   index  measurement  value
0      0            0     13
1      1            1      3
2      2            2      4
   index  measurement  value
3      0            0      8
4      1            1     12
5      2            2     34
6      3            5     54
```